# Function that is in $L^1(1,\infty)$ but not in $L^2(1,\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that not $L^1(1,\infty) \subseteq L^2(1,\infty)$ nor $L^2(1,\infty) \subseteq L^1(1,\infty)$ holds.

I have already found that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is in $L^2(1,\infty)$ but not in $L^1(1,\infty)$, meaning that $L^2(1,\infty) \subseteq L^1(1,\infty)$ doesn't hold.

What function would show that $L^1(1,\infty) \subseteq L^2(1,\infty)$ is not true?

Comment: You've got your inequalities (containments) all messed up.

Comment: The function you came up with shows that $L^2(1,\infty)\subseteq L^1(1,\infty)$ does not hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just consider e.g. $$f(x) := \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}, & x \in (5,6), \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$ Then $f \in L^1((1,\infty))$, but $f \notin L^2((1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

For a continuous example, let
$$ h(x) = \max(0, x(1-x)) $$
and take
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \cdot h(n^3(x-n)) = \lfloor x\rfloor\cdot  h\left(\lfloor x\rfloor^3(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)\right) $$

This function consists of a sequence of spikes of height ${\sim}n$ and width $n^{-3}$. The area of spike number $n$ is $\frac{1}{6n^2}$ for $f$ (in which case the sum converges) and $\frac{1}{30 n}$ for $f^2$ so not square-integrable.